# Line Rotation in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rotation

How can I make this line rotation work in IE8? I used [**this**](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/) to get the ms-filter but still wont work..

Here's a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ncrzB/).

Heres the HTML:

```
<div class="mainmenu">
    test
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.mainmenu:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333333;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    right: 12.5%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 35%;
    z-index:10000;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
     -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071067811865483, M12=0.7071067811865467, M21=-0.7071067811865467, M22=0.7071067811865483, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
}
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support standard CSS3 rotation, but it does have the `-ms-filter` style, which is capable of doing the same thing (albeit with much more complex syntax, and some annoying caveats).

However, if you're prepared to use a bit of Javascript, I would strongly recommend using a good polyfill script for this, which will allow you to use the standard CSS `rotate` syntax even for old IE versions.

The best polyfill script I know of for rotation is [CSS Sandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/#more-896).

Using this means you can use (near) standard CSS code, which means that (1)your code is more consistent between browsers, and therefore easier to maintain, and (2) you don't need to learn the horrible `-ms-filter` syntax.

So instead of the `-ms-filter` code, you'd have a line that looks like this:

```
-sand-transform: rotate(-45deg);
```

In addition to `rotate`, CSS Sandpaper also implements a variety of other CSS3 effects into old IE versions, which makes it a very useful tool.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform: rotate(45deg);  /* CSS3 (for when it gets supported) */
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
  filter: progid\:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
```

Comment: the comments in your code are somewhat out of date. Browsers have moved on a long way since then; the `transform` property is now supported without a prefix by all current browsers. (the prefixed versions are still useful for older browser support)

Comment: attempted it.. but it made no difference.. except the line was rotated the other way... but still nothing in IE8

Comment: arff okay.. I'll try to find something